# How to POST a list via jersey rest client

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have the following domain class

```
public class Team {
  private String name;

  // getters and setters
]
```

I have the following service endpoint

```
@Path("team")
public class TeamEndpoint {
    @Post
    @Path("registerAll")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String register(List<Team> teams) {
       // do something
       return "Fine";
    }

    @Post
    @Path("register")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String register(Team team) {
       // do something
       return "Fine";
    }
}
```

When I now try to use Jersey Client (2.23), I'm able to use `Entity.json(new Team())` to post to the method accepting one element - and everything is working as expected

But when I call the `registerAll` with `Entity.json(Arrays.asList(new Team())` I get

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1011)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:819)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:349)
```

How do I post a list of objects via Jersey client ?

==== EDIT ====

The Jersey client code looks like

```
private static String postList(List<Team> data) {       
    return ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(JacksonFeature.class).build()
       .target("http://server/team/registerAll)
       .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
       .post(Entity.json(data),String.class);
}
```

I assumed that its because `Entity.json` accepts `T` and not `List<T>` and I expected to need a `GenericType` or so - but I could not find any method accepting this.

Comment: Could you add your Jersey Client code too? might be helpful

Comment: Also, are you calling a `PUT` or a `POST`? Your code indicates POST but question title says PUT?

Comment: I will post the code - and sorry mixed up those two...I meant POST

Comment: added client code as edit in the post

Comment: argh - i found the culprit - in the domain class I have a builder, and therefore there was only a private constructor (which I have not shown here unfortunately, sorry for that).

Comment: Great! I wonder how your `/register` worked though.. because your lack of public constructor should've prevented single team object call as well! Please consider adding your comment as an accepted answer.

Comment: @NikhilPatil - for the sake of example I made it easier and the single example was from another class, but I didn't see the problem and showed here only one class... thought its less complicated then :( learned my lesson. Thanks for spending time on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the culprit.

My domain class is created by a builder and therefore has a private constructor. This provoked the problem. Offering a public constructor solved the issue.

The single object example worked as it actually was tested on another domain class, that had a public constructor. As I didn't see the connection and thought to simplify the description here - I showed only one domain class